# JBAS018717: No deployment content with hash [...] is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'foo.war'

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-eap-6

I am using Eclipse and I am trying to start the JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA server in standalone mode. But I am getting this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
18:34:12,699 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
18:34:12,952 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
18:34:13,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) starting
18:34:14,233 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SampleProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: "JBAS018717: No deployment content with hash a1ea5a3cbb12210e05b13a7f1d6271127deef8f3 is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'SampleProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."
18:34:14,233 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
18:34:14,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) stopped in 8ms
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?